# Auto mounting `NTFS` partition at startup not all options work

Tags: mount, permissions, ntfs, fstab

I am mounting a `Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit` system partition on my `Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit` installation in order to be able to share data between the two OSs. The problem is that although I explicitly give the option permissions in **/etc/fstab** file I cannot `chmod` the files or directories inside the mounted drive. I also experimented with it and noticed if I only supplied *permissions* option while mounting(after unmounting everything) it and changed into the mount directory I noticed that everything had `chmod 777` permissions, but I was able to alter the permission via the `chmod` command. The command is as follows in the command prompt:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g -o permissions /dev/sda5 /mnt/DATA/
```

However, I noticed even when I supplied my `uid` and `gid` to own the files the option `permissions` stopped having an effect. I tried appending and prepending it into the list of options just to make sure, and it turned out that in both cases I was not able to alter the permissions with `chmod`. The codes I used in command prompt is as follows:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o uid=1000,gid=1000,permissions /dev/sda5 /mnt/DATA/
```

After unmounting, one more try as follows:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o permissions,uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sda5 /mnt/DATA/
```

Both of these configurations did not allow me to change the settings and the option **permissions** had literally no effect. In my **/etc/fstab** file I define the line for mounting the **NTFS** partition as follows:

```
# data was on /dev/sda5 always
UUID=01CCA0086DD8A980   /mnt/DATA                 ntfs  auto,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=022,fmask=133,permissions       0       0
```

How can I make permissions options work so that I can change the permissions on the go without having to remount the partition totally? I read [somewhere in this website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition) it as possible, but I am unsure of how to do it. I would greatly appreciate any comments suggestions on this issue. My full **/etc/fstab** is as follows:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=c6cc14c0-aa75-4660-9e45-10a8fadedb64 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=30c60dd5-3c79-4e36-8ed7-d8035422f0b6 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=ffbc51d4-25b3-413f-aed1-14eba0f769c7 none            swap    sw              0       0
# data was on /dev/sda5 always
UUID=01CCA0086DD8A980   /mnt/DATA                 ntfs  auto,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=022,fmask=133,permissions       0       0
```

Comment: `permissions` and uses user-mapping, which conflicts with `uid` and `gid`. Pick one and stick with it.

Comment: @muru Sorry I did not understand what did you mean exactly, could you elaborate a bit on that? Did you mean that I cannot use `permissions` with `uid and `gid`? But using it with `user-mapping` is possible. Did I get it right?

Answer (score 2):

The best method I was able to find is the fstab entry below for the desired NTFS drive:

```
UUID=473577933B1627FB /media/username/Data\040Drive ntfs nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

You will have full permissions to the mounted drive.  This was done on ubuntu 14.10